# ERROR: syntax error at or near "set"

Tags: postgresql, sql-workbench-j

I am getting an error by executing following sql script code.

```
set search_path = 'RX_MIP'
set ON_ERROR_STOP on

\i import-products.sql
...
...
```

Error : syntax error at or near "set"

Can someone help me with above error.
I am using Postgresql DB and SQLWorkbench to execute scripts.
'RX_MIP' is a schema under by DB and that statement is getting executed successfully independently.

Comment: your `;` is missing :)

Comment: `ON_ERROR_STOP` is a `psql` variable and only available in `psql` - but it needs to be set using `\set`, not `set`  (but `\set` is also only available in `psql`). `set search_path = ...` on the other hand is indeed a valid SQL statement and as such needs a `;` at the end

Comment: I did that, but now it's giving ERROR: syntax error at or near "on"

Comment: I am using SQL Workbench/J to access postgres DB, will that statement only work in psql client or it can work in workbench as well?

Comment: `\i` is `psql` meta-command and will work in psql only, also read @a_horse_with_no_name comment. In short - the code above is definetely meant for `psql` only

Comment: In SQL Workbench you need to use [WbInclude](http://sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-wbinclude) to run a SQL script. And as I said: you can use **psql** variables like `ON_ERROR_STOP` **only** in `psql` and those require `\set`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the `psql` specific meta-commands `\i`, `\d`, ... are not supported by SQL Workbench/J

To run a SQL script use the [WbInclude](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/wb-commands.html#command-wbinclude) command